# My phone vibrates 2 times, as some application crashes inside or background

Tags: crashes, samsung-galaxy-ace

I have Samsung Galaxy Ace running Froyo.

While writing text, installing/removing app or doing any kind of play. My phone vibrates 2 times. Where as I am not using vibration for any event. You have also expirienced this vibration with a popup message that some application stop responding. But I didnt get that message. So that i can identify the porblem area. I guess some inside applicaiton crashes and this vibration happens.

Can any one give some pointer on it? How can I fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its difficult to find the Problem without the Device.
But you can Activate the Debug mode (*Preferences->Applications->Development->USB-Debuging*)
Then you can start Eclipse.
Open the DDMS Perspektive and there LogCat.

Perhaps you find there the BuggyApp.

Comment: I will try this.